# Performance problems while using azure face api for real time face detection

Tags: python, opencv, python-requests, azure-cognitive-services

I want to make a real time face recognizer with azure cognitive service's face api. But the api calls takes so much time. What can i do?

I wrote my code in the simple while loop. Grap a frame and detect faces in that frame. But the request part for detection faces is takes ~2.5 seconds. So, it's soooo far from real time detection :)
I found a c# example at their website but i couldn't handle. The link is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_face

```py
while True:
    image = getCapture()
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
    response = requests.post(vision_analyze_url,
                             params=params,
                             headers=headers,
                             data=image)
    print(response.json())
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

I'm even ok with 2 fps btw. What concept should i use? I saw something like asyncio, should i use it?

Comment: for real time usage, you need to use some other local libraries(like opencv). An api call is used for processing single image or when real-time result is not required.

Comment: Actually I'm also think as like you but the customer wanted that from me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, your performance issue was caused by two reasons.

1. The network latency of response per request, to reduce the time cost of the interval requests by using `aiohttp` based on `asyncio` concurrently.
2. It's a loop process running on a single thread, and wait for the response back and then to do the next one. Due to Python have no real concurrency mechanism by [`GIL`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), parallelly or concurrently to request the remote face detection api via [`Parallel Python`](https://www.parallelpython.com/) or [`ray`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray).

Basically, the two above is as same as the ideas of the offical document [`Example: How to Analyze Videos in Real-time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_face) for acceleration on face detection with video stream.

Otherwise, if you just need to do real time face detection, I think [`ageitgey/face_recognition`](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) based on [`dlib`](http://dlib.net/) may be a better solution for your scenario without cloud.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to perform the detection locally. You just need the model, completely removing the network latency.

Check this CV framework: https://github.com/pipeless-ai/pipeless